# How to send the id of an component to a function before it be declared?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to send the document.getElementById of an entry, that is defined after the entry that I am calling the javascript function and print it value, but the function alert to me that the component declared after is undefined, how can I acess it id and print it value?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user releases a key in the input field. The function transforms the character to upper case.</p>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction('fname', 'fname2')">
<input type="text" id="fname2">

<script>
function myFunction(first, second) {
    alert(second.value);
  var x = document.getElementById(first);
  x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `second` is a string, strings don't have a `value` property and thus gives you undefined.

I think you meant to have something like this:

```js
function myFunction(first, second) {
  alert(document.getElementById(second).value);
  ...
}
```